# Request transfered to different ASP.NET website (different domain, server etc)

Tags: asp.net, file, webforms, web, file-transfer

If I have a **Web Server A** which receives a request for a page/resource and I want to transfer the processing of that request to a different web server (**B**), is this possible in the ASP.NET web forms world?

I'm asking because if a user wants to click a page that serves up files, I want to analyse the http request and pick the closest server to them to serve up the file.

So:

1. User clicks hyperlink which is for www.a.com
2. www.a.com receives request, checks whatever it has to, transfers serving file to www.b.com
3. Client now receives content from www.b.com, not www.a.com

I basically do not want the file transfer to occur through www.a.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to do a Response.Redirect with the url to the proper server.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/), [Windows NLB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/ff711653) or [BIG-IP F5](http://www.f5.com/products/big-ip/).  There are tons of options for this, but ASP.NET doesn't do load balancing, it runs underneath IIS which is a single instance web server.